# Post each row of sqlite on my server in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I am working on an app that will post all the rows of my sqlite db in a server separately, when a broadcast receiver says that i have connection, it will throw and asynctask. To post every row.

I am pretty new at it. I already have the database full with a few rows

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to post row by row - pick all record at once and send a consolidated JSON to server by using asynctask to call a webservice/URL endpoint

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the data from the database in the asynktask